# Best IDE for Perl 5

Tags: perl

I have a good experience with Bash shell scripting and am now moving to Perl.

- What is the best IDE for Perl 5?
- Will Perl 6 kill Perl 5? Or will Perl 5 always be alive?

Comment: Perl6 is a completely different language, and is still in development. although it is already awesome, it is not production-ready. Take any editor you like, as long as it has decent syntax highlighting.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question warrants closing. Perhaps splitting into two questions and/or rephrasing though

Comment: @BrianAgnew - [It most certainly does warrant closing.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: You should check jetbrains official student bundle offer. You can get online free student licence in 20 seconds for all these ides. [https://www.jetbrains.com/student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/)

Comment: For future folks, the Perl 6 project has become [Raku](https://raku.org/).

Answer (score 26):

"Best" is, of course, a matter of taste. Rather than "best", I'll answer this as "what editor should I use for Perl if I don't already have a strong preference for an editor?" I went on a short quest to answer this question for my students.

What I recommend now is [Atom](https://atom.io/). It's free, open source, available on most platforms, well maintained, well documented, easy to use, and has a rich ecosystem of plugins. It works well enough for just about any language so you don't get trapped in a language-specific IDE. And it's powerful enough without being bloated.

I also recommend you learn [the basics of `vi`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-vi-editor.htm). This is the editor available on any Unix machine, and you'll need to use it when you inevitably find yourself needing to edit files on a Unix machine. It is very powerful, but also very baffling.

Atom has rendered the rest of this answer obsolete.

---

<strike>[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) is an IDE dedicated to Perl, however it hasn't seen a release in years.</strike>

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (and all its variants) and [vim](http://www.vim.org/) (and all its variants) remain excellent, powerful, but quite baffling to anyone not used to them. Still, you should know at least the `vim` basics for when you inevitably find yourself needing to edit files on a Unix machine.

For Mac, there's [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) (emacs that acts like an OS X app with expected OS X hotkeys and menus) and [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/).

On Windows [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and [E Text Editor](https://github.com/etexteditor/e) (no longer maintained) are good choices.

As for Perl 6, Perl 5 and Perl 6 are different languages with their own lives and development cycles.  Neither one will kill the other.

Comment: On Windows, I like [pspad](http://www.pspad.com) better than Notepad++.

Comment: The E Text Editor Link is dead.

Comment: @wp78de Thanks, turns out E Text Editor hasn't seen a release in years, nor Padre. Atom has rendered this answer obsolete, I've updated it for people who come upon it looking for advice.

Comment: This answer is horrible :( At the (mostly perl 5) company I work for, people with Atom had to find workarounds to open some ancient scripts with thousands of lines of code and in general doing any serious work on it was very slow. Even typing on big files had visible lag. Everybody switched eventually, to either VScode, Sublime, IntelliJ Idea. All far superior. I guess you don't notice in a classroom with small scripts, but it is definitely not for production.

Comment: @Ecuador I've heard such complaints about Atom in the past, but you may want to check again. I opened up my Perl lib and played with some large files. perl5db.pl, for example, at 10k lines. It's fine on my 2018 i7 Macbook Pro. Perhaps it lags on less beefy hardware, I'd be interested to know. Since I wrote this, VSCode has become also a very good option which fits the criteria: powerful, modern UI, free, cross-platform, language agnostic. But I don't use that, so I can't personally recommend it. Sublime and IntelliJ, while also said to be very good, both cost money.

Comment: @Schwern, I did check again. You seem to be right, I got the latest version and editing files that would choke it a year or so ago seems to work OK. It was too slow for too long to trust it now over VSCode or Sublime (small fee for commercial usage) AFAIC. Worth noting that EPIC and IntelliJ (with plugin and not sure of the free "community edition") allow perl debugging on the IDE.

Answer (score 12):

For your first question, the best one for you is the most suitable one for you. I realise this *isn't* an answer as such, but for comparisons of features, see [this chart](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Perl%20Development%20Tools).

With respect to your second question, I'm largely baffled by how close to release Perl6 is (e.g. see [this blog entry](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl6/index.cgi?when_will_perl_6_be_released)). I don't know of any of my clients using Perl6, and given this and the extant documentation for Perl5, I would reach for Perl5 with little fear of being overtaken in the near future.

Comment: From the Perl6 Wikipedia page, 'As of 2014, multiple Perl 6 implementations are under development, but none of them are considered "complete"'. My opinion re the 2nd point remains the same

Answer (score 4):

You can check EPIC plugin for Eclipse. Far from having all features, but you can do some debug and use Eclipse feature quite easily.

You can go safely with Perl 5. Perl 6 is a new language still being worked on and its date of release is unknown, so you shouldn't care about it for now.